# How to hide the RESET button from a record through DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Can anyone tell me how to hide the RESET button using DOM? 
I am trying to make a uservent script with beforeLoad function that will hide/remove RESET button from a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
var form = ctx.form;
var field = form.addField({
  id: 'custpage_code',
  type: 'inlinehtml',
  label: 'Code'
});

field.defaultValue = '<script>' +
  'document.getElementById("resetter").style.display = "none";' +
  'document.getElementById("tdbody_resetter").style.display = "none";' +// removed the extra line along the button
  '</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The other alternative is JQuery which is already pre-loaded in NS.

```
var hideFld = context.form.addField({
    id:'custpage_hide_buttons',
    label:'not shown - hidden',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML
});

var scr = "";
scr += 'jQuery("#tbl_resetter").hide();';
scr += 'jQuery("#print").hide();';

hideFld.defaultValue = "<script>jQuery(function($){require([], function(){" + scr + ";})})</script>"
```

You can hide *almost* any element with this. Just search the page source for the element ID:

The "Reset" button's element is usually a table with the ID `tbl_resetter`. Add multiple elements easily as above.